# When installing Newman, i get error "'newman' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Tags: npm, postman, postman-newman

I have Nodejs and NPM installed on my computer, and i'm trying to install Newman to run my Postman collection, but after writing on my command line "npm install -g newman", i get the following warnings:-

1. npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
2. npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher
3. 5 packages are looking for funding run `npm fund`

Then when i run "newman -v" on my command line, i get eror message "newman' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file". I canät really get to install newman, what could be the issue?

Comment: What is the operating system you installed on?

Comment: @janitha000 it's windows 10

Comment: Check whether C:\Users\{User Name}\AppData\Roaming\npm\newman is available. If so try to run from that location.

Comment: @janitha000, yes, newman is available in that location, but when i click "newman -  command script", command line appears to open then closes immediately.

Comment: Run  C:\Users\{User Name}\AppData\Roaming\npm\newman -v

Comment: Yes, i did run that way and i get version 5.2.4

Comment: Add C:\Users\{User Name}\AppData\Roaming\npm to your path variables. Open a new terminal afterwards and it should work. https://phoenixnap.com/kb/windows-set-environment-variable

Comment: @janitha000, I have created an environment variable named 'Newman' with the path as the value, but just wondering if every time i want run newman, i have to specify the path or just  C:\Users\{User Name}\Newman?

Comment: Sorry, I posted the wrong link. You don't need to create a new env variable. Just add the C:\Users\{User Name}\AppData\Roaming\npm\ to the existing path variable. You don't need to give the full path afterward. https://www.architectryan.com/2018/03/17/add-to-the-path-on-windows-10/

Answer (score 0):

for windows command line :

```
setx path=C:\Users\{User Name}\AppData\Roaming\npm;%PATH%
```

this will set the environment variable PATH permanently, just run this in cmd

Comment: i did wrote as you said, but got "Invalid syntax", type SETX for usage.

Comment: @DanAroka are you using windows comandline ?

Comment: @DanAroka replace the npm path with the path where your npm is don't reuse the command as it is

Comment: i'm not sure i understand what you mean. So i should not use "setx"? My current comand line is as follows:- C:\users\{User Name}\. What should i write after that?

Comment: you should find where the module are getting installed and then set it as 

`setx path=C:\Users\pathto\npm;%PATH%`